# How to grep the JSON array contains in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Consider:

```
   var dummyArray =  [{
        "fname": "gali",
        "lname": "doe"
    }, {
        "fname": "john",
        "lname": "danny"
    }, {
        "fname": "joe",
        "lname": "dawns"
    }, {
        "fname": "liji",
        "lname": "hawk"
    }]

dummyArray = j$.grep(dummyArray, function(dt) {
             return (dt.fname== 'j');
});
```

How can I query the "fname" which contains letter "j" using the [grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function?

Comment: use `filter` to find ALL, and `find` to find first, or `some` to check if it exist at all) they returns: array, one, bool respetively

Answer (score 5):

Using the ECMAScript 5 standard function [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only return the elements matching the predicate:

Starting with "j"

```
var j = dummyArray.filter(function(o) {
    return o.fname.charAt(0) === 'j';
});
```

or, containing "j"

```
var j = dummyArray.filter(function(o) {
    return o.fname.indexOf('j') >= 0;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
dummyArray = $.grep(dummyArray, function(dt) {
    return dt.fname.indexOf("j") != -1;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nhmwk/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with vanilla JavaScript like so:

```
dummyArray = (function(){
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0, l=dummyArray.length; i<l; i++)
    if (/j/.test(dummyArray[i].fname))
      result.push(dummyArray[i]);
  return result;
}());
```

You can easily test stuff by changing the regex. For example, you could test for names that **start** by `j` instead of **contain** with `/^j/`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/2Bw2y/

Comment: why accumulate your own array when we have `$.grep` and `Array.filter` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *index of* function:

```
dummyArray = $.grep(dummyArray, function(dt) {
    return dt.fname.indexOf("j") != -1;
});


// To be case-insensitive, use:
dummyArray = $.grep(dummyArray, function(dt) {
    return dt.fname.toLowerCase().indexOf("j") != -1;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kYXPa/